# Spring Strict Transport Security (HSTS) configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, strict-transport-security

I'm trying to enable HSTS in my Spring Boot application. I've added the following to my WebSecurityConfig (based on [Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) with spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511702/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-with-spring-boot-application/53522560#53522560)):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // Other http configurations, e.g. authorizeRequests and CSRF
        // ...

        http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .maxAgeInSeconds(Duration.ofDays(365L).getSeconds())
            .includeSubDomains(true);
    }
}
```

I *do* get the `strict-transport-security` header when in HTTPS requests, but the max-age is always `0`:

```
strict-transport-security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
```

I'm getting the exact same header if I *don't* add the Spring configuration, so it looks my configuration is not being picked up. It appears to be specific to the HSTS configuration, because the other configurations, e.g. `http.authorizeRequests()`, are working. That seems to indicate that the HSTS configuration is somehow being overwritten, especially when considering that [Spring's default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-hsts) max-age is one year. However, I've been able to find any other HSTS-related configuration in our codebase.

I also tried setting a breakpoint in `o.springframework.s.c.a.w.c.HeadersConfigurer.HstsConfig#maxAgeInSeconds` to check whether it's being called more than once. My call from `configure` was the only invocation.

Does anyone know why my HSTS configuration is not used? Or do you have any other ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was caused by a Cloudflare configuration that rewrote the header and set the max-age to 0.

It was also easier to update the Cloudflare configuration than to update the configuration in every micro-service.