# Can't set the Strict-Transport-Security header in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to set Strict Transport Security header to my Spring Webflow App.

This is the code that I have written to set the response header

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.headers()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .includeSubDomains(true).maxAgeInSeconds(31536000).and()
            .cacheControl().disable()
            .frameOptions().disable();       
    }
}
```

Now, I am checking the response headers for the urls and although the other two headers (cache-control and frame-options) are being set, but I am not seeing Strict Transport Security header anywhere.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Are you testing with HTTPS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511702/enable-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-with-spring-boot-application

Comment: @XtremeBiker yes

Answer (score 1):

The default `RequestMatcher` used in `HstsConfig` is checking if a request is HTTPS `HttpServletRequest.isSecure()`. If it's not sufficient for you due to some reasons, you can use another matcher.

The code below ensures that the `Strict-Transport-Security` header is set in all responses:

```
    http.headers()
          .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
          .requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
          ...
```